# How can I test my handwritten digit model using keras to detect new input image?

Tags: python, keras

I have trained my model for handwritten digit recognition  using keras(python) . Now I want to test my model for a new external input image of a handwritten digit.How should  I preprocessed  my image and how to get actual output?
please find this github link.  https://github.com/Kundan8296/Machine-Learning/blob/master/Handwritten%20digit.ipynb

Comment: please attached you code, thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Is it not working? In what way?

Answer (score 0):

You should preprocess the new image the same way you preprocessed images for the training and then call the function `model.predict(external_image_preprocessed)` where `external_image_preprocessed`, as the name suggests, is a image you want to predict but preprocessed the same way you preprocessed the images for training.

I hope this helps :)